# Displaying a infowindow based on the geometry in the fusion table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

**Problem :** have to place a marker and infowindow without knowing the latitude and longitude

**Explanation:**

I have a fusion table with some data and geometry(that defines the region).

Below is the snippet that let me hightlight the neccessary region with the query.

But now i have to set a marker on that neccessay region.but i don't have the latitude and longitude of that region

but i do have is the geometry of the region in the fusion table.

Please suggest me a way.

**Snippet:**

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1j2RT5lmo9*********v-WRXMKSM-2jNsV1pcEc',
    where: "CODE = 'S2801'"
    },suppressInfoWindows:true,styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: "#FC0",
      fillOpacity: '1.0',
      strokeWeight:"int"
    }
  }]});
```

Comment: Query the FusionTable for the coordinates of the region, find its bounds and place your marker on the center of the bounds.

Comment: [Example that does that for polygons in the sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html) so the infowindow opens at the center of the bounds of the polygon (uses GViz/google.visualization library for the query).